# Vaadin 8 TwinColSelect component is not in the center

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

In Vaadin TwinColSelect component the selection button has gone down. The select and deselect button should be in the center in-between the right and left list.

Comment: Small Code to reproduce?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and due a bug Chrome 76+ NG layout algorithm. It will be fixed in Chrome 79. See more details in our issue tracker https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/11712